# Select not binding to mode

Tags: angularjs, ng-options, angularjs-orderby

I have a select, populated via ng-options. When I submit the form, the model of the select isn't coming with. I can get it working if I don't use orderBy, but when I add an orderBy filter the options get sorted the right way, but the model of the select isn't sent any more.

So this code works:

```
<select ng-model="vm.administrator.communeId"
        ng-options="commune.communeId as commune.name for commune in availableCommunes"></select>
```

But this doesn't:

```
<select ng-model="vm.administrator.communeId"
        ng-options="commune.communeId as commune.name for commune in availableCommunes | orderBy:'name'"></select>
```

EDIT:
This part of the code is abandoned in the project I'm working on, so I don't have time or need to get to the depth of it.

Comment: try order by communeId, why are making alias in ng-options?

Comment: I just need the id, not the whole object and now the options are ordered by communeId by default.

Comment: could you make a plunker?

Comment: I took it upon myself to recreate, and I have no issues - passing the model back to controller and then back to `$scope` to be displayed upon click of `orderBy` name.. http://plnkr.co/edit/2MI9M9I0ac0X5MusNOgQ?p=preview

Comment: Thank you @xeon48 it must be something else in my code that is preventing the model from showing up. Thanks for the Plunker and for helping clear that up!

Comment: Cool, hope you figure it out.  If you want to edit your question and add more code in I'm very bored at work :)

Comment: It's quite a complex project, so difficult to give the whole picture.